# C# operator overloading does not work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

These is my code:

```
    public static Symbol operator + (Symbol op1, Symbol op2)
    {
        Symbol op3 = new Symbol() { op3.type = Type.Value };

        object o1 = null;
        object o2 = null;

        object replacement;
        try
        {
            o1 = op1.value.Value;
            o2 = op2.value.Value;

            if (o1 is string || o2 is string)
                replacement = o1.ToString() + o2.ToString();
            else if (o1 is double && o2 is double)
                replacement = (double)o1 + (double)o2;
            else
                throw new Exception("only to be caught");
        }
        catch
        {
            op3.type = Type.Invalid;
            op3.value = null;
            replacement = op3;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("ExpressionEvaluator {0} + {1} = {2}", o1, o2, replacement));

        op3.value = new Naked(replacement, typeof(bool));
        return op3;
    }
```

I gate the following error:
One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Is this a compile time error, or a run time error ? what line is the error on ?

Comment: what line of code gives you the error when running in the debugger ?

Comment: when i try op3 = (Symbol)operandStack.Pop() + (Symbol)operandStack.Pop();

Comment: do you not get an error within your overloaded operator ?

Comment: No, when i try to use the operator.

Comment: Please do not use exception handling as mainline control flow. It's a very bad practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the error it sounds like you declared your `operator+` inside a type other than `Symbol`.  C# requires that at least one of the types listed in the binary operator be the type in which the binary operator is defined

*Update*

As Eric pointed out, when the declaring type is a `struct` (named say S) then one of the operands must be `S` or `S?`

Answer (score 6):

That means that the operator has to be declared in the `Symbol` class.